# simple_form_for: update a part of the content with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml, simple-form

I have a form which call a partial:

```
# form.html.haml
= simple_form_for(resource) do |form|
  = form.input :foo
  = render partial :some_fields, locals: { form: form }

# _some_fields.html.haml
= form.input :bar
```

My problem is I have to update the partial with ajax and I don't know how to create the form var from my controller:

```
def ajax_form_fields
  render partial :some_fields, locals: { form: ? }
end
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to achieve this is to add this line at the beginning of _some_fields.html.haml:

```
- form ||= nil; simple_form_for(resource) { |f| form ||= f }
```

So, I don't need to pass the form var to the partial:

```
def ajax_form_fields
  render partial :some_fields
end
```